# Internal Field name not returning value

Tags: 2013, javascript

I am using an OOTB field entitled Email that does not seem to be working. I have a  really simple code that on change of the field value a pop up will return that field value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var textarea=$(":input[title='Email']");
          textarea.blur(function(){            
              alert(textarea);         
         });
});
```

I have looked in the HTML code on the form and it returned this:

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"> 
        <h3>class="ms-standardheader">
             <nobr>Email Address<span class="ms-accentText" title="This is a required field."> *</span></nobr>
        </h3>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">
    <!-- FieldName="Email Address"
         FieldInternalName="Email"
         FieldType="SPFieldText"
      -->
    <span dir="none"><input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" id="Email_fce16b4c-fe53-4793-aaab-b4892e736d15_$TextField" title="Email Address Required Field" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true"><br></span>
    </td>
```

It seems the out of the box solution does not work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("input[id^='Email']").blur(function() {
      alert( "Event Fired" );
    });     
});
```

Your code didn't worked because jQuery was trying to select `input` element which has `title` equal to `Email`. But as you can see rendered HTML doesn't have any such element.

My fix was to find `input` element which has `Id` starts with `Email`.

Comment: You Sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you so much!